# Postgresql: Searching a string with similar characters

Tags: postgresql

I have a POSTGRESQL Database with names like:

```
ʿImād ad-Daula Abu ᾽l-Ḥasan
```

The user may select this value by typing into a text field. But I would like the user to use similar characters. **So, that he can type: "imad" or "hasan".**
And still get the same result.

It seems a kinda basic problem to me, but I have not found a solution so far.

I tried it with:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name ILIKE '%hasan%' ORDER BY name ASC
```

But it doesn't work for these characters.
I would be really greatful for suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the extension `unaccent`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

And then you are able to do:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE unaccent(name) ILIKE '%hasan%' ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, on a first glance, that works great! :)